# Store queryable GeoJson in mongoDB with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm trying to be able to query to my database for specified parts of a large GeoJson file. The original file is formatted as such:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "GEO_ID": "xxxxdhuxxx",
                "STATE": "01",
                "COUNTY": "029",
                "NAME": "Cleburne",
                "LSAD": "County",
                "CENSUSAREA": 560.100000
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [-85.388717, 33.913044],
                        [-85.380885, 33.873508]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "GEO_ID": "xxxxuiuyxxx",
                "STATE": "01",
                "COUNTY": "031",
                "NAME": "Coffee",
                "LSAD": "County",
                "CENSUSAREA": 678.972000
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [-86.030441, 31.618939],
                        [-86.004085, 31.619067],
                        [-85.999948, 31.619311],
                        [-85.980098, 31.619189],
                        [-85.926702, 31.618966],
                        [-86.030441, 31.618939]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My current Mongoose Schema is a Nested Schema formed as such: 
GeoJson.model.js

```
`var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Features = require('./Feature.model.js')

//Example schema with possible input types.
var GeoJsonSchema = new Schema({
"type": { "type": String },
"features": [Features]
  });`
```

And Feature.model.js

```
`var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var FeatureSchema = new Schema({
"type": { "type": String},
"properties": {
  "GEO_ID": String,
  "STATE": String,
  "COUNTY": String,
  "NAME": String,
  "LSAD": String,
  "CENSUSAREA": Number
},
"geometry": {
  "type": { "type": String },
  "coordinates": []
}
  });


module.exports = mongoose.model('Feature', FeatureSchema);`
```

I Keep getting Validation Error So something is wrong but I just cant spot it. Any ideas?

Comment: All supported types are listed in the manual, [GeoJSON Objects](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/geojson/). `FeatureCollection` is not among the supported types. You can use `GeometryCollection` or rather just model these as individual documents within a normal MongoDB collection.

Comment: Related: [What is the best or recommended way to store a GeoJSON FeatureCollection in MongoDB?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/101688)

Comment: the polygon with two points seems fishy.  Formatted json is easier to read. https://jsonlint.com/